# Action fired, but state not updated in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a basic action which will fire a number of events.

```
export const ADDED = 'cartridge/ADDED';
export const REMOVED = 'cartridge/REMOVED';
export const SUBSCRIBE = 'cartridge/SUBSCRIBE';
export const UNSUBSCRIBE = 'cartridge/UNSUBSCRIBE';
export const SUBSCRIPTION_READY = 'cartridge/SUBSCRIPTION_READY';
export const SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR = 'cartridge/SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR';

export function subscribe() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { meteor: { client: Meteor } } = getState();
    const sub = Meteor.subscribe('cartridges');
    Meteor.ddp.on('added', function (document) {
      const { name, id: _id, fields } = document;
      dispatch({ type: ADDED, payload: { _id, ...fields } });
    });

    dispatch({ type: SUBSCRIBE, payload: sub });

    sub.on('ready', () => dispatch({
      type: SUBSCRIPTION_READY
    })).on('error', payload => dispatch({
      type: SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR,
      payload
    }));
  }
}
```

finally, on my reducer, I do the following (abridged).

```
export default function cartridges(state={
  data: {},
  isReady: false,
  isSubscribed: false
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case SUBSCRIPTION_READY:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isReady: true
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However, while this action DOES fire (can be seen in `redux-logger`), it never catches the action in the reducer. why would this be?

Comment: Are you importing the constant `SUBSCRIPTION_READY` in your reducer?

Comment: yep, I did that part

Comment: @corvid, there are many cases why your action is not handling by reducer, can you provide your full reducer code with all imports on `pastebin` service?

Comment: Is your reducer registered in the store? Please, provide a code where you create your store.